# Google Insights Search CSV keeps downloading in Spanish

Tags: windows, language, localization

If you do a search on [Google Insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#), you are given the option to download a CSV.

I wrote a small service which downloads it for me, every hour.  I have a site which then parses the report and shows it to the end user.

On my local machine everything works fine.

On my Windows 2003 Server, the report downloads in Spanish.  When on the Server, I load up IE, and browse to the site - it is also in spanish.  So I set it to English.

If I close IE and re-open - Insights appears in Spanish. It is the only google site which appears in Spanish - nothing else appears in spanish.  My regional settings and browser language are all set to English - United States.

Anyone have any idea why IE would keep reverting the site to spanish?  I've setup IE to accept cookies, and still it reverts to Spanish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the URL contains something like `hl=es`?. If yes, delete it; if not, add `&hl=en` to force the language to English.

Comment: I actually thought I tried that but apparently not.  Thanks buddy.